# Как действует этот код?

Tags: python, ооп

```
class Setting:

    def __getattribute__(self, prop):
        out = super().__getattribute__(prop)
        on_body = hasattr(super().__getattribute__('__class__'), prop)
        return out() if callable(out) and not on_body else out
```

Задание было такое: вы находитесь в процессе создания нового фреймворка. Чтобы повысить гибкость, когда ваш пользователь присваивает значение атрибуту экземпляра, вы хотите дать им возможность вместо этого предоставить вызываемый объект без аргументов. При доступе к атрибуту должно быть возвращено либо назначенное значение (как обычно), либо результат вызова (если он определен как вызываемый).

Создайте класс с именем "Setting", который поддерживает шаблон «Необязательно вызываемый атрибут».

Comment: В чём у вас вопрос? Тут вроде всё понятно. Берём свойство, если оно `callable`, но не класс - вызываем, иначе отдаём как есть. Дело в том, что класс - он тоже `callable` (чтобы получить экземпляр класса нужно вызвать класс) и поэтому на класс нужно дополнительно проверять. В `return` тут использован *тернарный оператор*.

Answer (score 0):

Тут вроде всё понятно.

1. Берём свойство
2. Если оно `callable`, но не класс - вызываем, иначе отдаём как есть.

Дело в том, что класс - он тоже `callable` (чтобы получить экземпляр класса нужно вызвать класс) и поэтому на класс нужно дополнительно проверять и отсеивать эти случаи.

В `return` тут использован *тернарный оператор*.